# Applications are greyed out

Tags: applications, external-sd, restore

I have a samsung galaxy Y with android 2.3.6(Ginger bread) installed.
I connected my mobile to a computer infected with virus and my sd card contents were moved into another folder.
I restored the contents to the previous location but I do not see any applications installed in the sd card in my mobile now.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely forgot to restore the "hidden folders". Apps moved to SDCard are placed into a hidden folder called `.android_secure`. Check whether you can find that anywhere, and then restore it as well to its original location. After that (and another reboot), your apps should be back.

Comment: Unfortunately I uninstalled the apllications as they were not working.Is there any way to reinstall them without downloading them again?

Comment: Only if you've kept their `.apk` files, sorry.